# Фиксированное позиционирование

Tags: css, position, позиционирование

Доброго времени!
Есть элемент, спозиционированный фиксированно:

```
element{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Он изначально не присутствует на странице, а подгружается динамически (по клику) и помещается внутрь блока "parent".
Среди его родителей есть один с относительным позиционированием:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper" style="position:relative">
    <div id="parent"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

На элемент изначально навешен класс *hidden* (в таком виде он уже приходит).

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

После подгрузки элемент должен отобразиться на странице, занимая, соответственно всю область браузера. Его обрабатывает вот такой скрипт:

```
var w = $(element).innerWidth();
var h = $(element).height();
$(element).css({
    'top'     : '50%',
    'left' : '50%',
    'margin-top' : -(h/2),
    'margin-left': -(w/2)
});
$(element).removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');
```

Класс *shown* только устанавливает *display:block*.

Проблема в том, что ширина и высота элемента почему-то отсчитываются не от области окна браузера (чего я, честно говоря, ожидала при фиксированном позиционировании, а от того самого элемента *wrapper*, у которого относительное позиционирование. Из-за этого в момент расчетов высота элемента равна высоте всего документа и соответственно, маргины рассчитываются неправильно, элемент оказывается слишком высоко.
После того, как убирается класс *hidden*, высота становится равной высоте окна браузера, как и должно быть. Элемент исчезает за верхней границей экрана.

Почему фиксированно позиционированный элемент (даже невидимый, даже неподгруженный), рассчитывает свои размеры относительно другого элемента, а не относительно экрана? Или это нормальное поведение и мне нужно менять всю верстку?

Временный костыль, который позволяет правильно отображать элемент:

```
$('.wrapper').css('position','static');
var w = $(element).innerWidth();
var h = $(element).height();
$('.wrapper').css('position','relative');
$(element).css({
    'top'     : '50%',
    'left' : '50%',
    'margin-top' : -(h/2),
    'margin-left': -(w/2)
});
$(element).removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');
```

АПД: Добавила элементу *display: block*, ничего не меняется. У *body* и *html* указана *height:100%*.

АПД: Видимо, проблема не в самом относительно позиционированном элементе, а в том, что если фиксированный блок имеет display: none, скрипт возвращает не его настоящую высоту, а высоту ближайшего позиционированного элемента.
Можно ли как-то получить настоящую высоту скрытого фиксированного блока?

Comment: Уберите со скрипта $('.wrapper').css('position','relative');
потому что дочирние елементи в wrapper позиционируютса относительно нево

Comment: @vov4ok Этой инструкции в скрипте нет. Это костыль - я убираю на время относительное позиционирование, чтобы правильно рассчитать размеры, а потом снова его устанавливаю. Оригинальный скрип вообще не воздействует на wrapper. Вопрос в том, почему фиксированно спозиционированный элемент отсчитывает свои размеры относительно другого элемента, а не экрана.

Comment: если можно полний код посмотреть

Comment: @vov4ok Полный код огромен. Какие конкретно моменты непонятны?

Comment: Насколько я понял надо проследить чтоби паренти били абсолютно спозиционирование и размер тоже зделать подходящий.

Comment: @vov4ok Какой тогда смысл в position:fixed? Мне необходимо, чтобы элемент позиционировался относительно окна, а не относительно родительских элементов, какими бы они не были, и чтобы он занимал 100% окна браузера.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n5v3j4yn/1/ Чтота такое?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53559/discussion-between-vov4ok-and-furry-cat).

Answer (score 1):

Получается так:

- если элемент фиксированно спозиционирован и его размеры заданы в процентах
- при этом он скрыт (display: none)

браузер не может вычислить реальные размеры данного элемента и на запрос скрипта возвращает размеры ближайшего позиционированного элемента.

В общем, логично, просто сразу картинка не сложилась.